# create edge from 2 unrelated classes

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have 2 classes that have a common property but are independent of each other.

I would like to create a linkset between the classes but unsure what the best scenario or path is.

class Items
has property "id"

class Item_Images
has property "item_id"

I would like add to Items, a property "Images" which is a linkset to the item_images class.

Am unsure of 2 things.

1) If I am better off creating an edge or if a linkset will suffice.
2) Proper syntax to relate the 2.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I actually created a link on the related properties. However, the syntax i am using to retrieve properties of the child record is very heavy and taking a performance hit

Comment: ```select *, $images as images from items
LET $images = (select expand(@this.exclude('@rid')) FROM
(SELECT from Item_Images where @rid IN $parent.current.Images))

Comment: Try lightweight edges.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you want just link the records or link them and add some additional properties on edge. In the last case you should use edges. If you don't need properties on an edge you can use lightweight edges or links for better performance.  For proper syntax see theese pages on official documentation:

- [SQL - CREATE EDGE](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Edge.html)
- [SQL - CREATE LINK](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Link.html)

Hope it helps.